# Google Charts Setting vAxis To 0.25 Intervals

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My data will always be in intervals of 0.25 on a line chart. I will never have a point such as 100.14. It will always be numbers such as 100, 100.25, 100.75, 500, 680.50

But when charts are drawn all to often I get vAxis numbers such as 1.1 or 2.4 when these values could never be a "point" on the graph.

I'd like to ONLY show multiples of 0.25 ... or ONLY show actual points on vAxis not "filler" points between two points.

I currently have these options

```
  var options = {"title":"#{chart_title}",
                 "colors":["#0088cc"],
                 "titleTextStyle": {
                     color: "#0088cc",    
                     fontName: "Verdana",
                     fontSize: 24, 
                     bold: true,    
                     italic: false   
                  },
                  "hAxis": { 
                             "textStyle": {
                               "fontSize": 14,
                               bold: true
                             }

                            },
                  "vAxis": { 
                             "textStyle": {
                               "fontSize": 18,
                               bold: true 
                             }

                            }          

                 };
```

Is it possible to force Google charts to always show multiples of 0.25 on vAxis?

OR even the vAxis only needs labels for actual points on the line graph. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `vAxis.ticks` option to set specific axis labels...

```
vAxis: {
  ticks: [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1, ...]
}
```

to build the labels dynamically, use the `getColumnRange` method on the data table,

```
var dataRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
```

which returns an object with properties for `min` and `max`

use values to build `ticks` array...

```
var vTicks = [];
for (var i = dataRange.min; i <= dataRange.max + interval; i = i + interval) {
  vTicks.push(i);
}
```

(add `interval` to `max` to allow a little extra room at the top)

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y');
    data.addRows([
      [0, 0],
      [1, 0.25],
      [2, 1.25],
      [3, 2.75],
      [4, 3.50],
      [5, 2.25],
      [6, 1.75],
      [7, 0.50]
    ]);

    var interval = 0.25;
    var dataRange = data.getColumnRange(1);

    var vTicks = [];
    for (var i = dataRange.min; i <= dataRange.max + interval; i = i + interval) {
      vTicks.push(i);
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        top: 12,
        right: 12,
        bottom: 48,
        left: 48,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      },
      height: 800,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      vAxis: {
        ticks: vTicks
      }
    };

    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
    function drawChart() {
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```